# Filtro em Collection Multidimensional Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collection

Possuo uma `collection` laravel com a seguinte estrutura :

```
"data": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "uuid": "c375f93d-2075-48c4-b80f-820c97a2696a",
            "enterprises": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "Freeda Jones",
                    "enterprise_type_id": 28,
                    "enterprise_type": {
                        "id": 28,
                        "name": "Savanna Boyer"
                    }
                }
            ],
         },
    ]
```

Como posso realizar um filtro baseado em `enterprises -> name`? De modo que ele aceite eu pesquisar por exemplo apenas as iniciais da palavra na chave `name`.

Estou fazendo assim :

```
$query->collection= $query->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) {
    return collect($row['enterprises'])->contains('name',  $request->enterprise_name);
});
```

O problema e que isso so me garante a presença do nome inteiro no array,não sendo possivel filtrar por apenas as palavras iniciais como nesse caso poderia ser ***Freeda***,ou por qualquer outro caractere exemplo ***Jon***  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$query->collection->filter(function ($item) use ($request) {
    $match = collect($item->enterprises)->filter(function ($item) {
        return Str::of($item->name)->contains($request->enterprise_name);    
    });

    return $match->isNotEmpty();
});
```

Comment: Editei a minha duvida, o `startsWith` me garante o inicio da `String` ,mas existe algum método que eu possa busca a `String` em todo o valor??

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada e substituir o `startsWith ` por `contains` resolve o meu problema.